# how i get the order status in the magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento-2.1.3

```
public function getStatusOptions()
{       
    $options = $this->statusCollectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();        
    return $options;
}
```

How I can get the order status in the custom shipping method?

Comment: you want to fetch all order status like pending, processing, completed n all?

Comment: thanks for reply @Abhishek Panchal yes i want to get all order status in the custom module can you please tell me how i get and update ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your PHTML file. or else you can create helper function and call it anywhere in website.

Try below code to get all the Order State and Status code.

```
$manager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$obj = $manager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\Collection'); 
print_r($obj->toOptionArray());
```

Comment: where i put this code can you please explain ?

Comment: in your PHTML file. or else you can create helper function and call it anywhere in site.